# insert event in the google calendar api, type out of the office

Tags: angular, google-calendar-api

how can I create an out of office event and cancel all appointments during this time? i use Angular and Typescript.
I tried using this event but it didn't work

[image: my event message]

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example] describe any issues you are having with your current solution.   Images of code are not acceptable.   "I tried but this didnt work" also does not property describe the issue with your code.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Calendar API does not support event type **outOfOffice** option for new event creation.

Reported [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112063903?pli=1)